# How to get a value from returned result "Promise {$$state: Object}"

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-promise

I have this function where GetDataFactory.getDataById(reqData) is function with $http request and returns correct data and when this data arrives I want to use it in another function, but this way keeps returning me  "Promise {$$state: Object}"

```
    $scope.getData = function(id) {
                    var reqData = {
                        "id": id,
                        "access_token": $scope.access_token
                    };
                    var foo  =  GetDataFactory.getDataById(reqData).then(function(response) {
                        var foo = response.data[0];
                        return foo;
                    });

                    console.log(foo); // prints "Promise {$$state: Object}" 
        return foo;
}

$scope.anotherFunction = function(){
    var id;
    var bar = $scope.getData(id);
}
```

I'm asking how to return correct value of the data after this $http request is success then return it to another function and do whatever I want to do with this data? Assigning to $scope.foo type variable and timeout is not an option

Comment: `foo.then(function (value) { /* do something with the value */ });`

Answer (score 1):

Because the getData function makes an asynchronous request you always have to wait for it to complete before you access the data it returns. Your anotherFunction should look something like this:

```
var bar
$scope.getData(id).then( function(response) {
    bar = response.data
})
```

You'll probably also want to refactor the getData function to just return the promise from GetDataFactory.getDataById so it would simply look something like this:

```
$scope.getData = function(id) {
     var reqData = {
         "id": id,
         "access_token": $scope.access_token
      };
      return GetDataFactory.getDataById(reqData)
};
```

You've already isolated your data retrieval in a service. The getData function looks like a bit of overkill, but without knowing all of your requirements, perhaps not.